# Как верстать такого вида блоки?

Tags: html, css

как такое сверстать? спасибо за помощь!
[image: ysmcsshtml]

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант div'ы c абсолютным позиционированием.

Круглый див:

```css
    #round {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: blue;
     border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="round">
```

Треугольный div:

```css
#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle">
```

Comment: каким образом это поможет автору? типа вот вам гвоздик, вот вам винтик, попробуйте сделать автомат?